# How do I download a stream of images (not video, not GIF) from a website?

Tags: web-scraping, video, video-capture

The stream of images comes from fire watchtower cameras at [ALERTWildfire](http://www.alertwildfire.org/). When I select a camera and an interval, the video-like flow requires downloading each image one by one. Is there any way to get a cam interval at once? After looking at inspect option in Chrome browser, I’ve realized that each image (frame) has its own URL.

In the sources tab (Chrome), I got link of one frame as blob:http://www.alertwildfire.org/ce5dc864-aaef-4852-ac2b-25224c86d656.

There are as many links as total frame number the website prepared to stream like video.

Is there a way to get these frames, since it is possible to right click and save each frame on a pause. However, I do video analysis and it will take a lot of time to get all frames one by one.

Comment: You need to tag a programming language for specific advice. Most people would just use a language that allows file downloads from a URL. You have the links to these "frames" so what is the exact problem? (you need real links to image files not blobs).

Comment: The website delivers links after the "blob:". I don't have any experience on such scrapping, so I'm investigating a way of getting this frame like sequence of images in order that the website delivers to my browser. A hint would help a lot.